# Gradle "keyword" index like in Javadoc?

Tags: gradle

Where can I find a list of such `Gradle` "commands" or "keywords" (how do you call them?), like `dependencies`, `compile`, `repositories`, `sourceSets` and etc in alphabetical order, like in Javadoc? With explanation of what do they do, but not what are they intended for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [DSL reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/) - Gradle Build Language Reference.